# Iterating through HTML table row by row and comparing dates in cells using Javascript, running offline, in the browser, without external dependencies

Tags: javascript, date, html-table, iteration, row

I'm no programmer, but I've seen some amount of simple code here and there.
I was given a task. I asked around about how to solve it and I was told it could be done using simple Javascript, so I thought I would try to ask for help here.

I have an HTML file with a huge table in it structured like this.
And my task would be to somehow identify/filter/highlight/mark/color or make eye-catching those rows in which the date of the cell "table-date_two" is higher (newer date) than the date in "table-date_one".
So comparing the two dates in each row and mark/color/highlight/filter those where the second date is newer than the first.
Ideally the result is that a human can look at this rable with thousands or rows and quickly identify the ones where date_two is newer than date_one.
This needs to be inline Javascript that I can paste into the HTML file and open it in a browser on a computer not connected to the internet.

Thank you very much for any help!

The first person I asked for help suggested Regex and said that that is capable of searching for dates and comparing those but it turned out that I can't comprehend Regex it being mostly just characters and not words and it's all "nested" deeply. That was clearly not for my brain.

I'm somewhat familiar with HTML and I've seen JS embedded in it so I think that could be the route but I can't produce code on my own.

```html
<table class="stuff">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="one">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="table-date_one">4 May 2023, 12:52 am</td>
      <td class="two">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="three">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="table-date_two">3 May 2023, 7:11 am</td>
      <td class="four">some more stuff</td>
      <td class="five">even more stuff</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td class="one">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="table-date_one">17 November 2018, 5:33 am</td>
      <td class="two">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="three">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="table-date_two">1 May 2022, 3:42 am</td>
      <td class="four">some more stuff</td>
      <td class="five">some more stuff</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="one">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="table-date_one">12 April 2021, 11:22 pm</td>
      <td class="two">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="three">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="table-date_two">2 May 2023, 6:44 pm</td>
      <td class="four">some more stuff</td>
      <td class="five">some more stuff</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td class="one">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="table-date_one">21 April 2023, 10:10 am</td>
      <td class="two">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="three">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="table-date_two">2 May 2023, 5:21 am</td>
      <td class="four">some more stuff</td>
      <td class="five">some more stuff</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally SO is not for e-lance requests, we do expect some effort from the asker.

It is trivial for those in the know.

Note the msSinceEpoch might need to be changed if you find a browser that does not parse your date string well, since [only the ISO 8601 format (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ) is explicitly specified to be supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

The script goes in the head of your page inside `<script></script>` tags, the CSS in a stylesheet.

```js
const msSinceEpoch = str => Date.parse(str); // returns an int 

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { // on page load
  document.querySelectorAll(".stuff tbody tr").forEach(row => { // ignore the thead
    const dateCell1 = row.querySelector(".table-date_one"); 
    const dateCell2 = row.querySelector(".table-date_two"); 
    if (!dateCell1 || !dateCell1) return; // skip rows that do not have both cells
    const date1 = msSinceEpoch(dateCell1.textContent);
    const date2 = msSinceEpoch(dateCell2.textContent);
    const greater = date2 > date1; // true or false
    row.classList.toggle("highlight", greater);     // set if greater
    dateCell1.classList.toggle("greater", !greater); // set if not greater
    dateCell2.classList.toggle("greater", greater); // set if greater
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: red;
}
.greater { font-weight: bold;}
```

```html
<table class="stuff">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="one">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="table-date_one">4 May 2023, 12:52 am</td>
      <td class="two">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="three">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="table-date_two">3 May 2023, 7:11 am</td>
      <td class="four">some more stuff</td>
      <td class="five">even more stuff</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td class="one">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="table-date_one">17 November 2018, 5:33 am</td>
      <td class="two">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="three">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="table-date_two">1 May 2022, 3:42 am</td>
      <td class="four">some more stuff</td>
      <td class="five">some more stuff</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="one">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="A">No date</td>
      <td class="two">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="three">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="B">No date</td>
      <td class="four">some more stuff</td>
      <td class="five">some more stuff</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td class="one">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="table-date_one">12 April 2021, 11:22 pm</td>
      <td class="two">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="three">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="table-date_two">2 May 2023, 6:44 pm</td>
      <td class="four">some more stuff</td>
      <td class="five">some more stuff</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="one">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="table-date_one">21 April 2023, 10:10 am</td>
      <td class="two">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="three">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="table-date_two">2 May 2023, 5:21 am</td>
      <td class="four">some more stuff</td>
      <td class="five">some more stuff</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: I could make this work but only for a small part of the beginning of my table. After that I get "dateCell1 is null" in the console. 
edit:
There is a small row (<tr ... </tr)) embedded after a certain number of rows and this one has a different structure, it doesn't contain the same cells and the script hangs after encountering the first one of these and can't continue. I think I can mass delete these "non standard" rows and it will make it work. Thank your for everyone who gave an answer, I tired out them all but this one gave me the best result so far.

Comment: Is there a way for the script to just skip the rows that doesn't contain the cells it is looking for without giving "is null" error and stop executing? That would make this fool proof.

Comment: Of course. See update. If you had added such a row to your example I would have known to skip it

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table class="stuff">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="one">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="table-date_one">4 May 2023, 12:52 am</td>
      <td class="two">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="three">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="table-date_two">3 May 2023, 7:11 am</td>
      <td class="four">some more stuff</td>
      <td class="five">even more stuff</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td class="one">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="table-date_one">17 November 2018, 5:33 am</td>
      <td class="two">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="three">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="table-date_two">1 May 2022, 3:42 am</td>
      <td class="four">some more stuff</td>
      <td class="five">some more stuff</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="one">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="table-date_one">12 April 2021, 11:22 pm</td>
      <td class="two">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="three">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="table-date_two">2 May 2023, 6:44 pm</td>
      <td class="four">some more stuff</td>
      <td class="five">some more stuff</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td class="one">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="table-date_one">21 April 2023, 10:10 am</td>
      <td class="two">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="three">some text or link or image</td>
      <td class="table-date_two">2 May 2023, 5:21 am</td>
      <td class="four">some more stuff</td>
      <td class="five">some more stuff</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- Inline script -->
<script>
// A function that parses a date string and returns the amount of milliseconds
// between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 and the date.
const parseDate = (dateString) => {
  // Split the string into an array of strings using non alphanumeric characters
  // as the splitting condition.
  const parts = dateString.split(/[^A-z0-9]+/);
  
  // Preformatting for ISO 8601 date format that we'll be using later.
  
  // Get the first array member (the day) and ensure it is 2 digits.
  const day = parts[0].padStart('0', 2);
  // Get the second array member (the month) and get the first 3 characters.
  const month = parts[1].slice(0, 3);
  // Get the forth array member (the hour), add 12 if the sixth array member (am/pm)
  // is pm, to convert the hour to 24-hour format and ensure it is 2 digits.
  const hour = ((parts[5] === 'pm' ? 12 : 0) + parseInt(parts[3])).toString().padStart('0', 2); 
  return Date.parse(`${day} ${month} ${parts[2]} ${hour}:${parts[4]}:00 GMT`);
};

// For every row.
document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr').forEach(row => {
  // Get the date one cell element text, removing any leading or trailing whitespace.
  const dateOne = row.querySelector('.table-date_one').innerText.trim();
  // Get the date two cell element text, removing any leading or trailing whitespace.
  const dateTwo = row.querySelector('.table-date_two').innerText.trim();
  
  // If more milliseconds has passed for dateTwo than dateOne, then
  // dateTwo is more recent:
  if (parseDate(dateTwo) > parseDate(dateOne)) {
    // Do whatever manipulation you need here.
    row.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I thought it would be helpful to explain the code. I have limited the `.querySelectorAll()` call to the `tbody` `tr`s now, thanks!

Comment: I am trying to find browsers that cannot natively parse the string we have. Works in Edge, Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the rows and compare the cells containing the date.

```js
const theTable = document.querySelector(`.stuff`);

// convert rows (Nodelist) to Array ([...])
// and loop the rows
[...theTable.rows].forEach(row => {
  // convert the content of date cells to Date
  // Note: check in different browsers if this conversion 
  // of text to Date works everywhere
  const [dateOne, dateTwo] = [
    new Date(row.querySelector(`td.table-date_one`).textContent),
    new Date(row.querySelector(`td.table-date_two`).textContent),
  ];

  // compare and assign class when two > one or one > two
  row.classList.add(dateTwo > dateOne ? `markSecond` : `markFirst`);
  row.querySelector(`.moreOrLess`).textContent = dateTwo > dateOne ? `<` : `>`;
});
```

```css
tr.markSecond td.table-date_one {
  color: #c0c0c0;
}

tr.markSecond td.table-date_two {
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
}

tr.markFirst td.table-date_one {
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
}

tr.markFirst td.table-date_two {
  color: #c0c0c0;
}

.moreOrLess {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: red;
  padding: 0 5px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<table class="stuff">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="table-date_one">4 May 2023, 12:52 am</td>
      <td class="moreOrLess"><td>
      <td class="table-date_two">3 May 2023, 7:11 am</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td class="table-date_one">17 November 2018, 5:33 am</td>
      <td class="moreOrLess"><td>
      <td class="table-date_two">1 May 2022, 3:42 am</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="table-date_one">12 April 2021, 11:22 pm</td>
      <td class="moreOrLess"><td>
      <td class="table-date_two">2 May 2023, 6:44 pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td class="table-date_one">21 April 2023, 10:10 am</td>
      <td class="moreOrLess"><td>
      <td class="table-date_two">2 May 2023, 5:21 am</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: "All modern browsers support forEach on the Nodelist returned by querySelectorAll" => I meant the conversion of text to `Date`

Comment: I was referring to the `[...theTable.rows].forEach` which I would not myself use. since `document.querySelectorAll(".stuff tbody tr").forEach` works without the `[...]` . Your code still fails because your strange array of null you create

Comment: "strange" => it's called [destructuring assigment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: I know what it IS. But what you did until you changed it was not worrking at all. `const dateOne = row.querySelector('td.table-date_one'),  dateTwo =  row.querySelector('td.table-date_two');` is superior notation in my opinion. Your "destructuring" is quite useless.